# StructureMap error (No Default Instance defined...)

Tags: structuremap

My type accepts 3 decimals as arguments to the constructor, which I am attempting to set in the StructureMap.config XML file (see below).

Why do I get the following error?

> {"StructureMap Exception Code: 
>   202\nNo Default Instance defined for
>   PluginFamily System.Decimal, mscorlib,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"}

**Config file:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>    
    <StructureMap MementoStyle="Attribute">  
      <Plugin Assembly="MyAssembly" 
              Type="IMyType" 
              ConcreteKey="MyType"/>

      <DefaultInstance
       PluginType="IMyType, MyAssembly"
       PluggedType="MyType, MyAssembly"                                           
       arg1="1m"
       arg2 = "1m"
       arg3 = "1m"/>  

      <AddInstance
       Key="LateRooms"
       Name="LateRooms"
       PluginType="IMyType, MyAssembly"
       PluggedType="MyType, MyAssembly"                                                     
arg1="1m"
       arg2 = "1m"
       arg3 = "1m" />  
    </StructureMap>
```